# Creating breadcrumbs using custom post type with custom taxonomy pods - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

I've searched for a solution to add breadcrumbs using pods plugin to create custom post type with custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the YoastSEO has the built-in functionlity to make it work.
You can user Yoast SEO's built-in breadcrumbs functionality.

Open **YoastSEO>Search Appearance>Breadcrumbs>Taxonomy to show in breadcrumbs for content types** and choose the custom taxonomy created with pods.